# js charts and mysql not displaying all the data

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to display the population of each state in the US and show this in a bar chart. I am definetly a begineer at this so be kind :-)
[echo out of some of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH2Do.png)
[only one state is being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfn8B.png)

I seem to be able to connect to my database ok and echo out all the data but its not displaying correctly in the bar chart. It is just showing the last entry "Wyoming". Here is my code and help would be massively appreciated !!

```html
<?php
include("conn.php");


$query = "SELECT * FROM usa_pop2";

$result = $conn->query($query);


if (!$result) {
  echo $conn->error;
  exit();
}

//print_r($result);

?>





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.2/helpers.esm.min.js" integrity="sha512-JC8H/YEABKWyV0Q/pgk3GfyrUCEiESg3ZM8DMdI8XD4zlwgtFyezG2dSenJ9pxAtJU2Bds6YNKYThXaLQrf9bw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

  <title>Charts</title>

</head>

<body>
  <?php

  $states = "";
  $p2018 = 0;
  $p2019 = 0;
  $p2020 = 0;

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $states = '"' . $row["state"] . '",';
    $p2018 = '"' . $row["pop2018"] . '",';
    $p2019 = '"' . $row["pop2019"] . '",';
    $p2020 = '"' . $row["pop2020"] . '",';
    echo "<p> $states - $p2018</p>";




    ///note to self go back take a look at this and then you might need to do do comma seperated for the data
  }
  ?>




  <div class="container">
    <h2>my data</h2>



  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

  </div>

  <script>
    let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    // global options

    //Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
    //Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
    //Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontcolor = '#777';







    let popChart = new Chart(myChart, {
      type: 'bar', //bar, horiz bar

      data: {
        labels: [<?php echo trim($states); ?>],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Population',
          data: [<?php echo trim($p2019); ?>],

          backgroundColor: '#581845',
          borderWidth: 1,
          hoverBorderWidth: 3,
          hoverBorderColor: '#000'
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        },

        //Add the tooltips
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem) {
              return "€" + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel);
            }
          }
        },
      }

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're using your variables after the loop, so they only contain the data from the last iteration. Seems you need to build an array of data.

Comment: Thank you El_Vanja! I am a bit novice but where should I create the array of data?  I thought I had created the array just after the body tag  $p2018 = '"' . $row["pop2018"] . '",';

Comment: Yes, but you've only placed a single value there. You need to take all the values from the loop, place them in an array and then [pass that array to JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript).